# rough-in measuring

Tags: plumbing

I have a 20 year old toilet that needs replacing.  In measuring the rough-in for the new one, I see that the toilet is not the same distance from both side walls.  Which wall
do I use for measuring?  The closer wall or the one farthest away?

Comment: I measure the flange to the back then the closest wall as all toilets that I have installed are centered on the soil pipe or flange.

Comment: The side walls are not so critical- usually there are local codes that require a certain distance from each sidewall (here it is 15" minimum). It is the back wall to center of the waste pipe that is critical. Most common is 12" from finish wall to center of toilet flange. That said, I know Toto and some other manufacturers make a 10" rough-in if your waste piping is too close to the back wall.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in comments, the distance to the wall behind the toilet is the one that matters for rough-in. Side to side is not generally a tight fit for the fixture, though some older installs are a bit tight for people using it.

You are required to have 15" (or more) to either side if making a new one, but in replacing an old one you generally have the space you have, and "grandfathering" applies if it's a simple replacement, not a remodel.

The toilet is going to land on the flange and be centered on it, (or every one that I and Ed Beal have seen is) so not centered in the space, as the old one must have been...